# MariaDB in Azure Converted to Read-only mode

Tags: azure

We have a MariaDB instance in Azure following the specs

- General Purpose, 2 vCore(s)
- Auto Scale in Size
- No Read-Replicas

Previously It was in 10GB, after adding a couple of queries, the storage percentage went above 95%. Hence Autoscale is on, and the size of the db increased to 15GB from 10GB. Unfortunately on that the DB also becomes read-only mode. Does anybody have ever faced this kind of issue? If so what is the solution to disable read-only mode?

Tried the Following solution nothing works for me till now.

1. I followed this thread [Azure Sql Database Read Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518498/azure-sql-database-read-only), Hence the thread suggestion to wait for a couple of hours. But we are waiting more than 20 hours still the DB is on read-only mode.
2. I tried to log in to the DB via Azure CLI and try to disable the read-only by adding the following command `SET GLOBAL read_only = OFF;`. As a response, I Am getting I don't have the privilege to do so.